# Are SD card file systems cached somewhere?

Tags: external-sd, cache

After removing the SD card from the phone, is the file system tree still stored somewhere accessible? I previously used ES  File Explorer to view the contents.
In case it is phone specific, Samsung Galaxy S7 edge running Nougat.